# Firestore + Vue: When refreshing the page, how to avoid delay in data display?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, caching, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

Every time I refresh the page, a new query is made in the Firestore database to show (sometimes) the same data to the user.

It is a bookcase. The code below only reads data that has already been added:

```js
export default {
  name: "Shelf",
  date: () => ({ shelfName: "", books: [] }),
  async mounted() {
    const auth = getAuth();
    const db = getFirestore();
    const userID = auth.currentUser.uid;
    const userRef = doc(db, "users", userID);
    const userSnap = await getDoc(userRef);

    userSnap.exists()
      ? (this.shelfName = "Shelf: " + userSnap.data().name)
      : (this.shelfName = "Your Shelf");

    const userBooksRef = query(collection(db, "users", userID, "addedBooks"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userBooksRef);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      this.books.push({
        id: doc.id,
        addedIn: doc.data().addedIn,
        readIn: doc.data().readIn,
      });
    });

    this.books.map(async (book) => {
      const booksRef = doc(db, "books", book.id);
      const bookSnap = await getDoc(booksRef);

      book.authors = bookSnap.data().authors;
      book.title = bookSnap.data().title;
      book.thumbnail = bookSnap.data().thumbnail;
    });
  },
};
```

I'm not sure if I should look for a caching solution or if there is some other type of solution.
Below I show the `books` collection. It's important to say that within the `users` collection there is a collection called `addedBooks` that reference the id of each book below:

[image: Firestore_Books]

Comment: This is what global store (Vuex) is for.

Answer (score 3):

When refreshing the page, you're destroying the previous instance of your application and loading a new one. As such, your app will re-execute all of its queries just like it did the first time opening the app.

As Estus mentioned in the comments, this problem is often solved by storing your data in state, and then putting that state in localstorage. When your page is refreshed, you first load the state from localstorage (no delay), and then update the state with the current data from your query when it becomes available. You can implement this process manually as well without using a state management library.

When storing data in localstorage, make sure you update it every time the data changes, and clear it when you no longer need it.

Comment: Your explanation was very good !! I've been working with Vue.js for a little while and I still don't know the libraries. I'm researching more about Vuex and making sure its implementation is trivial and easy to understand.

Comment: @Arnon If this answer helped, remember to upvote and accept it to close the question :)

Comment: Yes, of course man. I'm just applying the concepts I'm learning about Vuex and trying to apply to my project. If I can "migrate" this file to Vuex without any doubt I will accept your answer. If not, I edit my question with something more specific.